# how insert mutiple recored in mysql with pdo prepared statment?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I want to insert 10 or more record in a single query via prepared statment, here is my code

```
$sql="INSERT INTO post (a,b,c) VALUES ";

$placeholder='';
foreach($result as $record){
   $arr=array($record[a],$record[b],$record[c]);
        $values[]=$arr;
        $placeholder.="(?,?,?),";
 }

$placeholder=rtrim($placeholder,',');
$sql.=$placeholder;

try{
    $res=$db->prepare($sql);
    $res->execute($values);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But, it's not work. Is it possible to do what I want to do?
and next question is what if I prepare statement and execute the statement 10 time?
does the connection recreate 10 time or not?(It's not good to connect to db a lot)
because in my real code I want to insert more than 1000 record into new table.

Comment: What you suggest "prepare statement and execute 10 times" is the correct approach to take - it will use the same connection ( unless you close and reopen on each iteration of loop )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building up the values to bind, your building up an array of arrays, this should just be an array of the values you want to bind.

```
foreach($result as $record){
     $values[] = $record[a];
     $values[] = $record[b];
     $values[] = $record[c]);
     $placeholder.="(?,?,?),";
 }
```

Or you can use array_merge() if you just want to add all values into the array.